file clarification after a laravel upgrade
I have just had my site upgraded to Laravel 10 as part of an uplift. A file has appeared in the site directory called users.######.encrypted and is tagged as a Laravel 9 inclusion.
I've removed the file and killed it from bitbucket, just wondering if anyone has encounted a file like this before.
Upon inspecting the file, its a single line of text/numbers/symbols
